Elastic Search package is missing
Magento 2 module magento/module-elasticsearch requires a package elasticsearch/elasticsearch but that package is missing any one has any idea for it
Public packagist:- https://packagist.org/packages/elasticsearch/elasticsearch


you should to use opensearch. ;)

@sarfarazAhmed, project is using opensearch only but this package is added by magento 2 core for backend compatibility and thus it requires this library

@sarfarazAhmed ultimately this public repo https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch is archieved or some noob developer at elasticsearch make it as private

We are aware that some of our public repositories are temporarily unavailable and are working towards resolving this.
See https://status.elastic.co/incidents/9mmlp98klxm1

Thanks for your info
